# Condition if customer_id is in list

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new column `existing_new_customer` with the following condition:
if `customer_id` is in `list_new_customers` list then add `new_customer` else `existing_customer`

```
list_new_customers = [12,22,31,23,42]
```

current df

```
customer_id 
13           
12           
53          
22          
43          
31          
23          
45          
42
```

desired output df

```
customer_id  existing_new_customer
13           existing_customer 
12           new_customer 
53           existing_customer
22           new_customer
43           existing_customer
31           new_customer
23           new_customer
45           existing_customer
42           new_customer
```

This is what I've tried so far but it does not work

```
df[df['new_existing_customer'].isin(list_new_customers)]
```

Comment: shouldnt you check customer_id instead of new_existing_customer? In other words, shouldn't it be `df['new_existing_customer'] = df[df['customer_id'].isin(list_new_customers)]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is `np.where` as described above. Alternatively you can use a `lambda` function:

```
df['existing_new_customer'] = df['customer_id'].apply(lambda x: 'new_customer' if x in list_new_customers else 'existing_customer')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `where` from `numpy` package, and do this:

```
import numpy as np
df['existing_new_customer'] = np.where(df['customer_id'].isin(list_new_customers),'new_customer','existing_customer')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
df['existing_new_customer']  = np.where(df.customer_id.isin(list_new_customers), 'new_customer','existing_customer')

new_customer = df[df['existing_new_customer'] == "new_customer"]
existing_customer = df[df['existing_new_customer'] == "existing_customer"]
```